# An algorithmic problem: find the minimum number of operations to reduce each number in an array to 0

Tags: c++, algorithm

Recently I came across an algorithmic problem which is described below:

> Given an array of positive integers, you can pick any consecutive interval within the array and subtract every number within that interval by the same value, ask how many times at least the above operation is needed to make all the numbers in the array 0.

I'm trying to use greedy algorithm but I'm running into local minima problem, so I realized that I have to use dynamic programming but I can't find the recursion formula, am I thinking correctly? If not what is the correct way of thinking? Can anyone give me a hint about this problem?

I have seriously thought about this problem but I just can't come up with a result and it's frustrating me

EDIT:

here is my solution: using greedy algorithm, every time choose to the lowest number in the interval, subtract every number within the interval by this number, do this recursivly until all numbers are zero.The C++ implementation is as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int foo(std::vector<int> &v, int l, int r) {
    int min = 0x3f3f3f3f;
    vector<int> idx;
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        min = std::min(min, v[i]);
    }
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        v[i] -= min;
        if (v[i] == 0) {
            idx.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    cout << "l: " << l << "r: " << r << " delete: " << min << endl;
    if (idx.size() == r - l + 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int res = 1;
    int tmp_l = l;
    for (int x : idx) {
        if (tmp_l < x) {
            res += foo(v, tmp_l, x - 1);
        }
        tmp_l = x + 1;
    }
    if (tmp_l <= r) {
        res += foo(v, tmp_l, r);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;
    int tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> tmp;
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
    cout << foo(v, 0, v.size() - 1);
}
```

testcase formation is as follow.(first line describe the size of array, second line describe numbers in the array)

```
5
3 3 2 3 3
```

my solution meets local minium in the following testcase:

```
10
2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

my solution gives answer 9 but the correct answer is 8.
the optimial process is

```
origin:
    2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3

1 - 0 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
2 - 0 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
3 - 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2
4 - 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 2
5 - 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 2
6 - 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2
7 - 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
8 - 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

it seems that finding the lowerest number every time is not the best stragery, in this test case, number 2 is selected at first whereas the minium number in the interval is 1.

Comment: *"subtract every number within that interval by the same value"* <<< is the subtracted value constrained to be positive? Or can we subtract a negative number?

Comment: @Stef yes, the subtracted value constrained to be positive, and so every value in this array must stay non-negative during the procedure

Comment: Dynamic programming doesn't seem to work here either. There's no way to convert a solution for a subproblem to a solution for a slightly larger subproblem.

Comment: @yixing Can you describe your current approach and give the smallest example where it fails to be optimal?

Comment: Informally, it seems you are looking for a heuristic that in each step minimizes the number of unique values in the array.

Comment: @Dave I add my solution and wrong testcase in EDIT section

Comment: How large can the array and the numbers be?

Comment: @KellyBundy The size of the array is not currently a determining factor for this algorithm, and it can be assumed that the size of the array is between 0 and 100. It is now in the proof-of-concept stage of an algorithm

Comment: @500-InternalServerError perhaps minimizing the number of *sequences* with a unique value is better.

Comment: The optimal strategy in your example appears to be to always use the left-most non-zero value and extend the sequence to its maximum length from that starting point without going negative.

Comment: @phatfingers yes, the optimial strategy I show up is just one better strategy to this testcase to  demonstrate my greedy algorithm isn't always optimal,  I want to find out a general algorithm that suitable for all situation, so maybe a bit misleading.

Comment: What about the algorithm proposed by @phatfingers? Is there a counter-example where that does not work?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort?

Comment: @Matt Do you mean affecting the outcome, or just how you implement a solution?

Comment: @tobias_k [1,3,2]? (Matt's in reverse)

Comment: @tobias_k As I showed elsewhere, `[2, 5, 10, 7]` is a counterexample.

Comment: @KellyBundy I mean is the OP allowed to sort the input.  If so it becomes trivial to find the first non-zero number and subtract it.

Comment: @Matt: Changing the order would be the same as removing the "consecutive" limitation in "you can pick any consecutive interval within the array and subtract every number within that interval by the same value"

Comment: Sorry to miss the interesting discussion，@tobias_k I have implemented the algorithm and It works well to given testcases, but I can't figure out whether It is good for all the testcases, I find @btilly gives me a detailed answers，I will  read it to get more infomation

Comment: I restored my answer. Do you have some more interesting examples or a link to an online judge?

Comment: Just a comment: in @yixing's "difficult" case subtracting 2 first is not the only way of getting a final answer of 8; subtracting 3 first would give the same answer and the 3 is neither the leftmost element, nor a local minimum.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an algorithm, but I do have a proof that it is NP-complete by a reduction from subset sum.

Let `S = [s1, s2, ..., sn]` be an array of `n` positive integers, and `k` be another positive integer. Consider the following numbers.

```
[s1, s1+s2, s1+s2+s3, ..., s1+s2+...+sn, k]
```

This is solvable in `n` steps if and only if `k` is the sum of some subset of the numbers from `S`.

I actually do know a way to solve this with [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). But there is a combinatorial explosion. Here is an outline of the idea.

Given an optimal answer, we can rearrange the order of the terms so that we're always subtracting from the first non-zero term. And the heuristic is that there is some number `m` of places where the value in the list changes. We can only reduce `m` by at most 2 with a single subtraction (we can eliminate both edges potentially). So the ceiling of `m/2` is the least number of steps left.

---

I was asked for evidence of the reduction.

The "can be done if `k` is a sum of a subset of `S`" part is simple. The blocks removed are of heights `s1`, `s2`, ..., `sn`. The `i`th block goes from index `i-1` to either index `n-1` or `n` depending on whether `i` is one of the terms in the subset sum.

The "only if" is more complicated.

First, to make indexing easy, let's replace `S` with an array. So instead of saying `s1` we'll say `S[0]`. (Note, there will be lots of off by one indexing issues.) And therefore our example array with `n+1` elements is

```
a = [a[0], a[1], ..., a[n]]
  = [S[0], S[0] + S[1], S[0] + S[1] + S[2], ..., S[0] + ... + S[n-1], k]
```

Now suppose we can zero out the whole array with `n` blocks. Using the fact that addition is commutative, let's rearrange the blocks by the first index removed. This guarantees that we zero out the numbers in the array from left to right. Let's let `taken[i][j]` be the amount taken from `a[j]` after the first `i` blocks are taken.

Note that `taken[0][j]` is always zero, because we have not yet subtracted out anything.

Suppose that `a[j]` is not yet zeroed out after `i` blocks. Every block so far must start at or before `j`, and possibly only some continue to `j+1`, so `taken[i][j] >= taken[i][j+1]`. Since `a[0] < a[1] < .. < a[n-1]`, this means we can only zero out at most one per block. Since we manage to zero out all `n` of those with `n` blocks, we must zero out one of those indexes per block. (And, at some point, we'll manage to zero out `a[n]`, which is `k`.)

Now our goal is to see that `taken[i][j]` must always be the sum of a subset of `[S[0], S[1], ..., S[i-1]]`. This will mean that `taken[n][n]` is. And since that zeroed out `k`, that means that `k` is the sum of a subset of `S`.

We will do this by showing something stronger.

If `i <= j < l` then `taken[i][j]` is the sum of a subset of `[S[0], S[1], ..., S[i-1]]`, and `taken[i][l]` is the sum of a subset of that.

First, the trivial case. `taken[0][j]` is always `0` because when we have taken 0 blocks away, we haven't taken anything away. `0` is, of course, the sum of a subset of the empty set. And the empty set is a subset of the empty set.

We'll do `i=1` by hand. We need to zero out `a[0] = S[0]`. Therefore the first block has height `S[0]` and some length, meaning that `taken[1][j]` has to be either `S[0]` or `0` depending on whether you're off the end of the block. And once it turns `0` it stays `0`, so if `j < k` then `taken[1][l]` is the sum of a subset of `taken[1][j]`.

And now for the general induction case. The `i`th block needs to finish zeroing out `a[i-1] = S[0] + S[1] + ... + S[i-1]`. We have already taken away `taken[i-1][i-1]` which is a sum of a subset of `[S[0], S[1], ..., S[i-2]]`. And therefore the `i`th block is the sum of the complement of that set in `[[S[0], S[1], ..., S[i-1]]`.

If `i <= j`, then `taken[i-1][j]` is the sum of a subset of `taken[i-1][i-1]`. Therefore the elements of `S` in the `i`th block are **NOT** already in `taken[i-1][j]`. Therefore whether or not the `i`th block is included in `taken[i][j]`, you get the sum of a subset of `[S[0], S[1], ..., S[i-1]]`.

Now suppose that `j < l`. We already had `taken[i-1][l]` is the sum of a subset of the terms that made up `taken[i-1][j]`. The `i`th block may or may not be included in `taken[i][j]` and `taken[i][l]`. But if it is included in `taken[i][l]` then it MUST be included in `taken[i][j]`. This leads to three cases, in all of which `taken[i][l]` is a sum of the subset of the terms that are part of `taken[i][j]`.

So by induction we have the result. And as already noted, that means that `k = taken[n][n]` is the sum of a subset of `[S[0], S[1], ..., S[n-1]]`. So solving this problem for the array `a` leads to a solution of the subset sum problem.

Comment: @KellyBundy the correct preposition should be "from".

Comment: @KellyBundy No, we ask whether the *second* sequence (of n+1 numbers) is solvable in n.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI and Kelly, I fixed the preposition.

Comment: @KellyBundy I added an outline of why it is that `k` must be the sum of a subset of `S`. In essence each block that reaches `a[n-1]` is a sum of some subset of `S` that is disjoint from every other block that reached there. Some of those blocks then reached `a[n]`, and represented `k` as a sum of disjoint subsets of `S`, which is to say a subset of `S`.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is only of modest size you can do it by a recursive search ... but the time complexity isn't great.

**EDIT:** code improved by:

- not spawning a recursion where improvement is impossible (there is a smaller positive value to left or right, or an equal value to the left);
- splitting up the subsequences into positive subsequences surrounded by 0s.

Can now get to about N=30 with reasonable running time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//======================================================================

template<typename T> ostream & operator << ( ostream & out, const vector<T> &V )
{
   for ( auto e : V ) out << e << ' ';
   return out;
}

//======================================================================

int best( const vector<int> &V )
{
   int b = V.size();
   if ( b == 0 || *max_element( V.begin(), V.end() ) == 0 ) return 0;
   if ( b == 1 )                                            return 1;

   for ( int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++ )
   {
      // Reduce values around position i and put in a temporary vector
      int val = V[i];
      if ( i     > 0        && V[i-1] > 0 && V[i-1] <= val ) continue;    // no improvement possible
      if ( i + 1 < V.size() && V[i+1] > 0 && V[i+1] <  val ) continue;    // no improvement possible
      vector<int> temp = V;
      int imin = i, imax = i;
      if ( val > 0 )
      {
         imin = i;   while( imin     > 0        && V[imin-1] >= val ) imin--;
         imax = i;   while( imax + 1 < V.size() && V[imax+1] >= val ) imax++;
         for ( int j = imin; j <= imax; j++ ) temp[j] -= val;
      }

      int btest = ( val > 0 );
      int j1, j2;
      // Deal with left side of modified array in positive subarrays [j1,j2] surrounded by 0
      j2 = i - 1;   while ( j2 >= 0 && temp[j2] == 0 ) j2--;
      while( j2 >= 0 )
      {
         j1 = j2;   while( j1 - 1 >= 0 && temp[j1-1] != 0 ) j1--;
         vector<int> left( temp.begin() + j1, temp.begin() + j2 + 1 );
         btest += best( left );
         if ( btest >= b ) break;
         j2 = j1 - 1;   while ( j2 >= 0 && temp[j2] == 0 ) j2--;
      }
      if ( btest >= b ) continue;

      // Deal with right side of modified array in subarrays [j1,j2] surrounded by 0
      j1 = i + 1;   while ( j1 < temp.size() && temp[j1] == 0 ) j1++;
      while( j1 < temp.size() )
      {
         j2 = j1;   while( j2 + 1 < V.size() && temp[j2+1] != 0 ) j2++;
         vector<int> right( temp.begin() + j1, temp.begin() + j2 + 1 );
         btest += best( right );
         if ( btest >= b ) break;
         j1 = j2 + 1;   while ( j1 < V.size() && temp[j1] == 0 ) j1++;
      }
      if ( btest < b ) b = btest;
   }
   return b;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   vector<vector<int>> tests = { { 3, 4, 1, 2 },
                                 { 3, 4, 1 },
                                 { 3, 3, 2, 3, 3 },
                                 { 2, 5, 10, 7 },
                                 { 2, 5, 0, 2, 5 },
                                 { 4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4 },
                                 { 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 } };

   for ( const auto &v : tests ) cout << v << "----> " << best( v ) << '\n';

   const int N = 30;
   vector<int> v( N );
   srand( time( 0 ) );
   for ( int &e : v ) e = 1 + rand() % 100;
   cout << "\nRandom vector of size " << N << ":\n";
   cout << v << " ----> " << best( v ) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3 4 1 2 ----> 3
3 4 1 ----> 2
3 3 2 3 3 ----> 3
2 5 10 7 ----> 3
2 5 0 2 5 ----> 4
4 9 11 6 3 1 4 ----> 5
2 3 4 5 1 2 3 1 2 3 ----> 8

Random vector of size 30:
16 39 88 24 80 77 76 57 64 7 30 31 14 1 7 95 95 54 53 83 99 90 37 6 61 96 25 36 56 22  ----> 24
```

Comment: Thanks, this can help validate other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Consider each element as either rightmost of a disjoint section or in the middle or leftmost position of a disjoint section (by "disjoint," I mean a section where the reductions in it do not extend further). If it is rightmost of a disjoint section, it makes no sense to reduce the element more than once. Why? There are two cases: (1) we're reducing an equal length section twice (or more), which clearly makes no sense since we could reduce it once by the full amount for a lower cost; or (2) we're reducing a longer section first, then a shorter one (or more; we can reorder the reductions for similar effect). But the latter operation could be split into a separate move for each of those sections for the same cost.

```
11111111
    2222
```

would have the same cost as

```
11113333
```

If the element is not at the end of a disjoint section, it necessarily is first reduced by some ordered effect of the end elements that were fully removed, and the residual, if any.

JavasScript code:

```js
// Returns sums from cs that do not
// exceed n.
function getCombs(cs, n, i = 0) {
  if (i == cs.length) {
    return [];
  }
  
  const result = [];
  
  for (const [s, ks] of getCombs(cs, n, i + 1)) {
    result.push([s, ks]);
    if (s + cs[i] <= n) {
      result.push([
        s + cs[i],
        [cs[i]].concat(ks)]);
    }
  }
  
  if (cs[i] <= n) {
    result.push([cs[i], [cs[i]]]);
  }
  
  return result;
}

function f(A) {
  const dp = {};
  
  function g(i, cs) {
    const key = String([i, cs]);
    if (key in dp) {
      return dp[key];
    }
    
    const combs = getCombs(cs, A[i]);
    
    // Base case last/first element
    if (i == 0) {
      if (A[i] == 0) {
        return 0;
      }
      
      for (const [s, _] of combs) {
        // cost has been subsumed.
        if (s == A[i]) {
          return dp[key] = 0;
        }
      }

      // Otherwise, we don't apply the
      // sum and remove the element at
      // the cost of one full reduction.
      return dp[key] = 1;
    }

    // Skip when the element is zero.
    if (A[i] == 0) {
      return dp[key] = g(i - 1, []);
    }
    
    // Reduce this element fully.
    let result = 1 + g(i - 1, [A[i]]);

    // Reduce by a selection of
    // amounts that we pass as
    // options for the next element.
    for (const [s, ks] of combs) {
      if (s == A[i]) {
        result = Math.min(
          result,
          g(i - 1, ks)
        );
      } else {
        result = Math.min(
          result,
          1 + g(i - 1, ks.concat(A[i] - s))
        );
      }
    }
    
    return result;
  }
  
  return g(A.length - 1, []);
}

var inputs = [
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], // 8
  [2, 5, 10, 7], // 3
  [4, 9, 11, 6], // 3
  [2, 3, 1], // 2
  [3, 4, 1, 2 ], // 3
  [3, 4, 1], // 2
  [3, 3, 2, 3, 3], // 3
  [2, 5, 0, 2, 5], // 4
  [4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4] // 5
];

for (const input of inputs) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
  console.log(f(input));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "disjoint section"?

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks, added some language to clarify.

Comment: For example, what are the disjoint sections of [4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4]?

Comment: @KellyBundy what is the answer and sequence for [4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4] as you understand it?

Comment: I don't know the answer. What do you mean with "sequence"?

Comment: @KellyBundy I meant sequence of operations to solve it.

Comment: I don't know that, either. Input is just the array, in this case [4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, 4]. That's all that's known. Do the "disjoint sections" depend on such a sequence of operations? Then you should introduce that first. Otherwise the reader thinks you're talking about the input array (since that's all that's known) and doesn't understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Sequence: start -> 0 5 7 2 3 1 4 -> 0 0 2 2 3 1 4 -> 0 0 0 0 1 1 4 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 -> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  which is 5 operations.

Comment: @lastchance thanks for that sequence. It helped me look more carefully at the dimensions of the recursion.

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for that counterexample to the code I had. The current code seems to handle that one. The disjoint sections I meant are `[4, 9, 11, 6, 3, 1, | 4]`. Do you have another?

Comment: Oh, that wasn't intended to be a counterexample, was solely to hopefully see enlightening "disjoint sections". Which is still not really clear, as discussed in my previous comment.

Comment: @KellyBundy which part of "a section where the reductions in it do not extend further" can I help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding jargon, your goal is to zero as many digits as possible each time without splitting the remaining digits more than necessary.

The process is more or less as follows:

1. Collapse any contiguous number sequences (112233 is the same as 123 in this case).
2. Get all the possible max ranges (likely best handled with recursion to avoid duplicating ranges).
3. Get the count of numbers that can be zeroed in each range and subtract the number of times it occurs in the middle of a range.
4. Choose the range with the largest result from step 3. If there are multiple ranges with the same result, choose the biggest.
5. Subtract the smallest number from all items in the range chosen in step 4.
6. Add 1 to your step count and repeat from step 2 for each range bookended by 0s (or boundaries) until there are none left.

I will try to add some actual c++ code to this answer when I have a chance.